# Conceal some latex commands with more than two arguments in Vim

Tags: vim, latex

How do I conceal command in Vim using regular expression \pdv{(.*?)}{(.*?)}:

```
\pdv\{(.*?)\}\{(.*?)}  conceal to  ∂\1/∂\2
```

like:

```
\pdv{x}{t} -> ∂x/∂t
```

I tried to understand the Vim:Conceal documentation, but I did not. I would be glad if you offer a working method.